# How to remove the images from "Uploaded to this post"?

Tags: images, gallery

I was wondering if there's a simple way to deselect images from uploaded to this post, but still have the images in the image library?

I uploaded some images while i was editing a post and this isn't the same as uploading images with *Media > Upload*.

For example, I make a post with 4 images, but overtime I don't like to use the 4 images as this particular theme auto creates a gallery from the images. When selecting insert media these images are "Uploaded to this post".

How to deselect some of these images from *Uploaded to this post*?

Comment: Can you explain a little more? like with examples so that people here can better understand your need

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

You have to *unattach* the images from the post.
And that means setting their `'post_parent' => 0` in `wp_posts` database table.

The plugin [Unattach and Re-attach Media Attachments](http://wordpress.org/plugins/unattach-and-re-attach-attachments/) does exactly this, and it uses the following command to this end:

```
$wpdb->update(
    $wpdb->posts, 
    array( 'post_parent' => 0 ),
    array(
        'id' => (int)$_REQUEST['post_id'], 
        'post_type' => 'attachment'
    )
);
```